# Table creation order in declarative schema with different modules

Tags: magento2

Let's assume that i have a Module A that creates a tableA using Declarative Schema. And  a module B that creates a second table (tableB)that have a foreign key that points to table A using the same method (declarative schema). Does magento assumes that the order of creation in database is first tableA then tableB or i need to set the order using some directive (like 'sequence' in module.xml)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a table name and referenced column. Check out the official documentation https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html#create-a-foreign-key

Comment: I know that. My doubt is :
1) I need to set an order of module creation, since in database level i have an dependency?
2) If the answer is yes,  the only way is doing  in module.xml with <sequence> tag?

Comment: Not sure if this is the only way, but for sure is the right way to do it with the sequence.

Comment: @miwata have you been able to test and now know the proper of doing it? Am facing a similar situation.